# casting from extended class

Tags: java, inheritance, casting

I'm trying to access class `Weapon` so I can use method `getName()`, 
that is why I declared `w1` in my `getFleetWeaponNames` method but because the classes `Cruiser` and `Destroyer` don't extend the `Weapon` class I cannot cast them to `Weapon`

```
public class Cruiser extends Spacecraft implements ISpacecraft
public class Destroyer extends Spacecraft implements ISpacecraft
```

The Error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   starfleet.Cruiser cannot be cast to starfleet.Weapon  at
>   starfleet.StarfleetManager.getFleetWeaponNames(StarfleetManager.java:102)

```
/**
 * Returns an Arraylist of Strings of all names of all the fleet's weapons installed on any ship, without repetitions
 * in increasing order
 */
public static ArrayList<String> getFleetWeaponNames (ArrayList<ISpacecraft> fleet)
{
    Weapon w1;
    ArrayList<ISpacecraft> helpArraylist = new ArrayList<>(fleet);
    Collections.sort(helpArraylist , Comparator.comparing(ISpacecraft::getName));
    ArrayList<String> arraylistOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < helpArraylist.size() ; i++)
    {   if(helpArraylist.get(i) instanceof Destroyer || helpArraylist.get(i) instanceof Cruiser )
        {
            w1 = (Weapon)helpArraylist.get(i);
            arraylistOfStrings.add(w1.getName());
        }
    }
    return arraylistOfStrings;
}
```

Comment: `but because the classes Cruiser and Destroyer dose not extend the Weapon class it dose not giving me to cast to a weapon reference` - it seems you already know the cause of your problem.

Comment: He is not related

Comment: Am loocking for a way that giving the ability to use getName() method in weapon class

Comment: It seems to me that you are looking for a way to cast a `Spacecraft` to a `Weapon`, where both have nothing in common. How do you expect this to work?

Comment: Marvin hit it, it is not a technical issue, it is a problem of your domain design.

Comment: Ask yourself: Does a `Spacecraft` *have* one or more `Weapon`s, or *is* a `Spacecraft` *a* `Weapon`.